# Pitfalls of sending eNewsletters with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, spam

A client needs to send out eNewsletters.

We tried using their Sitefinity CMS, but it hangs for reasons that are hard to determine.

As a result, I am inclined to "roll my own".

However, various pitfalls yawn deep and dark along the imagined path.

For example:

### Imagined Pitfalls

1. My client's domain gets blacklisted.
2. The emails get rejected as Spam.

### Presumed ways of avoiding imagined pitfalls:

a.  Send out emails with a delay of, say, 2 seconds between each one.

b.  Send out emails individually, ie, no CC or BB.

### Questions:

- Are my imagined pitfalls and presumed
  ways of avoiding them correct?
- Can you think of other pitfalls?
- Or better ways of avoiding them?
- Do you know of reliable software that
  just does this (ASP.NET, MVC by
  preference, drawing form SQL Server
  db).

Comment: As a side note, are you using MVC with Sitefinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be beneficial to use a third party like Constant Contact to handle sending your email campaigns.  They expose an API that you can tap into via REST and it won't have any effect on your client's domain. Constant Contact is a reputable company and email campaigns they send out rarely get caught in Spam filters.  My company currently uses the service, but not the API and its been very successful.

[Constant Contact's Website](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp) 
[CC's API Web Site](http://developer.constantcontact.com/doc) 
[Example of creating a Campaign](http://developer.constantcontact.com/doc/manageCampaigns#create_campaign)

Comment: Will have a think.  Although another API to learn sounds depressing.  So still tempted with roll my own.  Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You should never do this.  Your client's IP(s) and domain(s) will find themselves blacklisted to the point that even their legitimate, hand-crafted emails won't make it past spam filters at large mail services.

Use something like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) if you want to stay closer to the metal than a service like MailChimp or Constant Contact.

Comment: That sounds pretty conclusive.  +1 for the suggested service.

Answer (score 2):

There are other companies out there which do it, such as [BriefYourMarket](http://www.briefyourmarket.com/) ... never roll your own :-)